# How to enable next and prev buttons on simple form

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I'm looking for a way to create some kind of form in my iPhone. I add for example 3 textfields and when I click on first one and write something in I want to be able to press next and it would take me to the next textfield.

link: http://shrani.si/f/3U/lB/3Nl9qXha/primer.png

I want to do something like if you fill in a web form.

Comment: Maybe you find a solution regarding or using this open source software http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks Next, you can use,

```
[nextTextFieldAlong becomeFirstResponder];
```

...to move the cursor to the next field.

Comment: Well my keypad doesnt have button next yet, i want to know how to add it... And what about prev?

Comment: Invoke becomeFirstResponder on whichever control you want to move to, either the previous or the next. [textFieldToMoveTo becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set tags for your fields (1-3) then set an accsesory view in your textfields like this

```
[messageView setInputAccessoryView:[self createAccesoryView]];
```

You can use a method like this to generate the accesory view (this was take from apple documents) :

```
    -(UIView*)createAccesoryView{
        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
        [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        [toolbar sizeToFit];
        UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Previous", @"Next", nil]];
        [segmentControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
        [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(selectNextPrevious:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        UIBarButtonItem *select = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentControl];
        UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTyping)];
        [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:select, flex, done, nil]];
        return toolbar;
    }
```

Then in `selectNextPrevious`

```
-(void)selectNextPrevious:(id)sender{
if ([(UISegmentedControl*)sender selectedSegmentIndex]==0) {
if (activeField.tag>1) {
            [[self.view viewWithTag:activeField.tag-1] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
 else {
        if (activeField.tag<numberOfFields) {
            [[self.view viewWithTag:activeField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that sounds great unfortunaly i dont have time to test it today. I will tell u tomorrow how it end.

Comment: Hi again i'm testing ur code but it doesn't work because i dont know what is        messageView in first line of code...

Comment: I figure it all out, i jsut dn/t know yet how to determine which field is active at the time...

Comment: messageView is just a name, you have to do that with all of your text fields

Comment: That first line goes in your viewDidLoad or something similar